# Получить последее значение в колонке из нескольких датафреймов и посчитать среднее

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть несколько датафреймов, в которых содержится колонка minutes (тип данных - objects). Нужно из каждого достать последнее значение из этой колонки и посчитать mean.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше это осуществить? Пробовала сделать так:

```py
for m in df['minutes']:
    m = m[:-1]
```

вид у них вот такой:

```
00:15:0
00:05:7
00:20:1
00:45:2
00:01:1
00:32:4
00:27:3
```

Значения достать получилось, но как посчитать `mean`?

Comment: Последнее значение по колонке или последнее значение в самой ячейке? В формулировке кажется, что одно написано, а в коде другое происходит. Распишите пример прямо в вопросе: вот есть такие данные (ок, вы их показали). Из них нужно получить такое вот значение - покажите в вопросе. И между такими-то значениями посчитать `mean` - покажите в вопросе опять же, из чего считать нужно среднее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если нужно буквально это:

> из каждого достать последнее значение из этой колонки и посчитать mean

то можно сделать так:

```
pd.concat([df['minutes'].tail(1) for df in dataframes]).mean()
```

но чтобы получить нормальный ответ поместите в своем вопросе пример исходных данных и пример того что должно получиться на выходе.